# How to call Django REST APIs using javascript/jquery/AJAX?

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, django-cors-headers

I want to call a Django Rest API in Frontend using Javascript, jQuery, AJAX. Request method is POST but when I see the API call its calling OPTIONS method. So, I came to know about `access-control-allow-origin` which needs to be allowed in APIs I guess. For that I used `django-CORS-headers` package but still its calling the `OPTIONS` method.

**code** is something like this :

```
jQuery.ajax({
            url: API_url,
            headers:headers,
            dataType: "JSON",
            type: "POST",
            crossDomain: true,
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
            success: function( response, jqXHR ) {
                    do something here
            }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I learnt this answer a long time back but forgot that I had posted this question then! 
So, Whenever an http request is made between two applications, browser does a `OPTION` request first to check whether the application is authenticated to make a request to the other application or not. If authentication fails, no other requests are sent. That's why if you do a postman request to an api, it will work without enabling the cors. So, to enable the cross origin request to work, Set key `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True` in django `settings.py` for enabling CORS for all domains. To whitelist specified domains set

`CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False`,

`CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = ('http//:localhost:8000')`

P.S.: You have to use `django-CORS-header` package.